# Setting up mobile hotspot/SoftAp on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, wifi, hotspot, access-point

As i have understood in Windows 10, the function to setup a hosted network from the console has been removed. Instead they are replacing it with a service called "Windows Mobile Hotspot Service".

Intel them self confirms this
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000023257/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

I have found that it can be enabled from settings in windows 10, but does anyone know if this can be done programmaticly? Either from CMD or com call etc?